# Saving an Altair visualisation with precise outer dimensions

Tags: altair

Is there a way to save an Altair visualisation as SVG automatically with precise outer dimensions?

My issue is that some elements like the legend are normally drawn outside the graph area and therefore the actual size of the outer bounds cannot be defined in the script.
One can set width and height to "container" load it in a web-page with a specific container size and then save the visualisation manually.

I am looking for a way to do it with for example vl-convert or altair-saver but could not find anything in the documentation.
Scaling the SVG afterwards gets the font-sizes to be wrong.